# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drvsupport' when using Fiona driver

Tags: geopandas, fiona

when I run the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import pandas as pd

gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
my_map = gpd.read_file('mymap.kml', driver='KML')
my_map
```

I get this error:

```
    gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drvsupport'
```

Can anyone please help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Recent versions of geopandas import fiona dynamically, and `gpd.io.file.fiona` is initially None.

My fix was to change to:

```
from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers
supported_drivers['LIBKML'] = 'rw'
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the latest version of python, geopandas and fiona this worked for me:

```
import fiona
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
```